# How can I grant roleAssignement/write permission to azure devops service connection

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, hcl

I am setting a staging environment for my Continuous Deployment. I am using the Azure devops service for repositories and pipelines.

I need to add Azure Active Directory login to my Linux VMs. So far I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/login-using-aad) guide. It works on my machine, although when I try to run it on Azure devops I get the following error.

```
2019-04-08T14:54:33.7657868Z ERROR: The client '********-****-****-****-************' with object id '********-****-****-****-************' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/staging-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/webscaleset/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/********-****-****-****-************'.
```

It seems that my azure devops service connection lack roleAssignment/write permission. I can not figure out how to add it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

easiest way - assign owner role to the service principal, you can find it using the service connection page, it has a link to "manage service principal" or something like that.

Alternatively you can create custom role that can only do that and assign to the service principal, a bit more secure, but not that much, since with that role you can grant any permissions to anybody.

Powershell to create custom role:

```
$role = Get-AzRoleDefinition "Virtual Machine Contributor"
$role.Id = $null
$role.Name = "Assign permissions role"
$role.Description = "Allow to assign permissions"
$role.Actions.Clear()
$role.Actions.Add("Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write")
$role.AssignableScopes.Clear()

Get-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {
    $scope = "/subscriptions/{0}" -f $_.Id
    $role.AssignableScopes.Add($scope)
}
$def = New-AzRoleDefinition -Role $role
```

Comment: I found the page you are talking about but there is no setting to change the service principal's role to owner

Comment: you can get service principal name from that page, to grant permissions use this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal

Answer (score -1):

Grant below role to the devops service principle

Name:Privileged role administrator
Description:Users with this role can manage role assignments in Azure Active Directory, as well as within Azure AD Privileged Identity Management. In addition, this role allows management of all aspects of Privileged Identity Management.